# Get only specific object within json in a data frame

Tags: json, r

I would like to import a single object from a json file into a R data frame. Normally I use `fromJSON()` from the jsonlite package. However now I want to load [this json](http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20132014/2013020555/PlayByPlay.json) into a data frame and then only the object that is called **plays**.

If I use:

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON("http://live.nhl.com/GameData/20132014/2013020555/PlayByPlay.json")
```

It gives a data frame containing all the objects. Is there a way to only load the **plays** object in the data frame? Or should I just load the complete json and restructure this within R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does return a dataframe, although it 's kind of a mangled gemisch of list and dataframe. If you use a different package, it is just a list. Using str(df) (warning ...long output)

```
library(RJSONIO)    
str(df)
#------------
List of 1
 $ data:List of 2
  ..$ refreshInterval: num 0
  ..$ game           :List of 7
  .. ..$ awayteamid  : num 24
  .. ..$ awayteamname: chr "Anaheim Ducks"
  .. ..$ hometeamname: chr "Washington Capitals"
  .. ..$ plays       :List of 1
  .. .. ..$ play:List of 102
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 28
  -----------Output truncated----------------
```

.... shows that the `plays` portions can be obtained with:

```
plays_out <- df$data$game$plays
```

I do not see that there is any advantage in trying to parse this yourself. Most of the "volume" of data is in the plays component.

When I use jsonlite::fromJSON I get a slightly different structure which is sufficiently different that I now I need to use a different call to get the `plays` items:

```
> str(df )
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ refreshInterval:List of 1
  ..$ data: num 0
 $ game           :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ awayteamid  :List of 1
  .. ..$ data: num 24
  ..$ awayteamname:List of 1
  .. ..$ data: chr "Anaheim Ducks"
  ..$ hometeamname:List of 1
  .. ..$ data: chr "Washington Capitals"
  ..$ plays       :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ play:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ data:'data.frame':  102 obs. of  29 variables:
  .. .. .. ..$ aoi          :List of 102
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num  8470612 8470621 8473933 8473972 8475151 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num  8459442 8467332 8467400 8471476 8471699 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num  8459442 8467332 8467400 8471476 8471699 ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num  8459442 8467332 8467400 8471476 8471699 ...
#------snipped output------------
> length(df$game$plays)
[1] 1
> length(df$game$plays$play)
[1] 1
> length(df$game$plays$play$data)
[1] 29
```

I think I prefer the result from RJSONIO::fromJSON, since it doesn't add the complexity of dataframe coercion.

Comment: If I do `plays_out <- df$data$game$plays` after using the `fromJSON` command I get an empty value called **plays_out**. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I'm not sure who is missing what. I used the `fromJSON` function in the 'RJSONIO' package which I loaded before I noticed that you mentioned "jsonlite"(without the quotes) in your text. That was why I added teh library call. I suppose it's possible that the structures we are looking at are different.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I switched to 'RJSONIO' package and this works.

Comment: And now struggling with getting this list into a data.frame. I already tried, from the plyr package, `df <- ldply (plays_out, data.frame)`, but this gives errors. Is there a way to get this in a data.frame?

Comment: Which list? If you want to work with the first `aoi` value it would be `as.data.frame(df$game$plays$play$data$aoi)`

Comment: Now I figured out what my problem was. The structure of the json isn't consistent for every entry. This created most of my problems.